# left join not returning NULL values

Tags: sql

I'm sure this is due to the fact that I don't know how to use LEFT JOIN, but I'm writing a query that is not returning NULL values. Here's the query:

```
CREATE TABLE #OrgMaster
(OrgName nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO #OrgMaster (OrgName)
SELECT DISTINCT Organization
FROM StageReleaseCalendar_VW

SELECT SRC.Organization
, SRC.deploytype
, COUNT(SRC.deploytype) AS 'Deployment Count'
, DATEPART(m,SRC.actualstarttime) AS 'MonthNum'
, DATENAME(m,SRC.actualstarttime) AS 'MonthNam'
 FROM #OrgMaster TTOM LEFT OUTER JOIN StageReleaseCalendar_VW SRC 
 ON LEFT(TTOM.OrgName, LEN(TTOM.OrgName)) = SRC.Organization
WHERE DATEDIFF(m, SRC.scheduledstarttime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
AND completerelease = 1
AND deploytype IN ('Service Pack','Hot Fix')
AND cancelled = 0
GROUP BY SRC.Organization, SRC.deploytype,  DATEPART(m,SRC.actualstarttime), DATENAME(m,SRC.actualstarttime)

DROP TABLE #OrgMaster
```

There are four organizations total: Commercial, Consumer, Partner, and Sales. After creating the temp table, if I then run the following query:

SELECT OrgName FROM #OrgMaster

The results are as follows:

Commercial
Consumer
Partner
Sales

Partner has no deployments of any kind in July or August, so what I'm trying to get is a set of results that includes four NULL records for Partner - a record for hotfixes in July, for hotfixes in August, for service packs in July, and for service packs in August. Instead, I get a result set that is limited to only those entries for which a deployment did in fact take place.

Can anyone see what I'm not understanding here?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a left join in the query.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - that was cut and pasted from an attempt to see if RIGHT JOIN would get me what I needed. I've corrected the post to include the query I am actually using, that I thought would give me the desired results.

Comment: Curious, what do you expect `LEFT(TTOM.OrgName, LEN(TTOM.OrgName))` to be? I think it's the same as `TTOM.OrgName`.

Comment: My thinking was that since I defined the length of the field in the temp table to be 100, I should trim down to just the actual value, minus any whitespace. That said, the output is the same whether I use that, or just TTOM.OrgName as you note.

Comment: Never seen some of the things you are doing here but I can tell you that if your where clause includes fields from the (right) table, you will never get nulls.

Comment: Steve, thanks. So if I remove the WHERE clauses, I should get the following total: (Number of Orgs) X (12 months) X (number of deploytypes), correct? If so, it's still not working for me. There are 4 deployment types, so I should get a total of 4 orgs X 12 months X 4 deploytypes = 192. I'm getting less than that, and when I look at the results, I don't see any records, NULL or otherwise, for months where an org didn't have a specific deploytype (i.e., still no records for Partner in July or August).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your where clause limits data by fields in your (right) table.  This will not give you the nulls.  To do this, I often encase my SELECT inside another SELECT (nested), so I can then query for nulls in the (right) table.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT a.ID as AID, b.ID as BID from TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
On ....
WHERE ...
) tmp Where BID is null
```

Comment: And this may be where I'm just completely misunderstanding joins. There are no NULL records in the right table - the records simply don't exist. I thought that a LEFT JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN would "force" a NULL record in the result if there was a record in the left table (such as PARTNER) that didn't have a corresponding match in the right table based on the conditions. I also tried switching the order of the tables so that the where clause was on the left table, but that didn't fix it either. It looks like I need to do some more learning here.

Comment: You are right, but by implementing criteria against the RIGHT table, you will not get the "NULL record", as you called it.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't make any difference. So it looks like I'm stuck. I can't get a count of the number of times an organization _didn't_ meet the criteria. which is what I really need.

Comment: Was working on this problem all night and that solved it for me. Thanks @HLGEM.

Answer (score 0):

The proper query

```
SELECT TTOM.OrgName 
, SRC.deploytype
, COUNT(SRC.deploytype) AS 'Deployment Count'
, DATEPART(m,SRC.actualstarttime) AS 'MonthNum'
, DATENAME(m,SRC.actualstarttime) AS 'MonthNam'
 FROM #OrgMaster TTOM LEFT OUTER JOIN StageReleaseCalendar_VW SRC 
 ON LEFT(TTOM.OrgName, LEN(TTOM.OrgName)) = SRC.Organization
WHERE SRC.Organization is null or 
 DATEDIFF(m, SRC.scheduledstarttime, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
AND deploytype IN ('Service Pack','Hot Fix')
AND completerelease = 1
AND cancelled = 0
GROUP BY TTOM.OrgName, SRC.deploytype,  DATEPART(m,SRC.actualstarttime), DATENAME(m,SRC.actualstarttime)
```

Another option would be to guard all the fields from SCR table in WHERE clause with ISNULL operator.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Plus, I think you can use this to get other good information as well.

```
DECLARE @OrgMaster as table(OrgName nvarchar(100),deptype nvarchar(100),MonthNum int,DeploymentCount int)
DECLARE @Loop1 int
DECLARE @Loop2 int

SELECT @Loop1 = 0, @Loop2 = 0

WHILE @Loop1 <> 2
BEGIN
    SELECT @Loop1 = @Loop1 + 1, @Loop2 = 0

    WHILE @Loop2 <> 2
    BEGIN
        SET @Loop2 = @loop2 + 1

        INSERT INTO @OrgMaster (OrgName,deptype,MonthNum)
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            Organization
            ,CASE WHEN @Loop1 = 1 THEN 'Service Pack' ELSE 'Hot Fix' END
            ,DATEPART(m,DATEADD(MONTH, -1 * @Loop2, GETDATE()))
        FROM StageReleaseCalendar_VW

    END
END


UPDATE @OrgMaster SET
    DeploymentCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM StageReleaseCalendar_VW 
                        WHERE Organization = OrgName
                            AND deploytype = deptype
                            AND DATEPART(m,actualstarttime) = MonthNum
                            )

SELECT * from @OrgMaster where DeploymentCount = 0
```