# Need Help Thinking Through Semi-Complex Query on Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables, and I want to create a SELECT pulling a single record from one table based on multiple records from another table.

Perhaps it will be clearer if I just give a sort of example.

**Table: dates. Fields: dosID, personID, name, dateIn**

```
1 | 10 | john smith | 2013-09-05
2 | 10 | john smith | 2013-01-25
```

**Table: cards. Fields: cardID, personID, cardColor, cardDate**

```
1 | 10 | red    | 2013-09-05
2 | 10 | orange | 2013-09-05
3 | 10 | black  | 2013-09-05
4 | 10 | green  | 2013-01-25
5 | 10 | orange | 2013-01-25
```

So what I want is to only select a record from the dates table if a person did not receive a "red" card. The closest I have come is something like:

```
SELECT name, dateIn FROM dates, cards 
WHERE dates.personID = cards.personID AND cardColor != 'red' AND dateIn = cardDate;
```

But for this query the 2013-09-05 date-of-service would still be pulled out because of the "orange" and "black" cards given on the same day.

I have tried searching but I am not even sure how to properly describe this issue and so my Google-fu has failed me. Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Whats the problem with above query ?

Comment: Essentially I don't want a date from the 'dates' table to appear AT ALL if a person was given a "red" card that day, but my current select query would output 2 of the 3 Sept. 5th dates and just omit the one with the "red" card. What I want is for no records from Sept. 5th to show if there was a "red" card given...

Comment: Sound like you want what this person wanted.  See if you can adapt this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883372/left-join-not-returning-null-values/18899880#18899880

Comment: @Steve Need to spend more time looking at this - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest to understand version would filter using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT name, dateIn
FROM   dates
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT *
         FROM   cards
         WHERE  cards.personID = dates.personID
            AND cards.cardDate = dates.dateIn
            AND cards.cardColor = 'red'
       )
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b29c/1/0).

Comment: Tried out your code and this seems to work! I suppose I need to read more about NOT EXISTS as I am having some trouble understanding it exactly, but you have given me a good direction! Much much appreciated.

Comment: @user2573020: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused, you're getting the non-red 2013-09-05 rows back.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89260

I tried it using an inner join (as you wrote it), and an outer join. Same results.

EDIT:
Sorry, misunderstood your post.
eggyal's answer looks like a winner to me.